# Nhibernate 3.x Cascade - Doing update

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following mapping, but when i delete status entity the Nhibernate executes an update on child instead of delete.

```
public StatusMap()
{
    Property(x => x.Date);
    Property(x => x.Text, map => map.Type(NHibernateUtil.StringClob));
    Property(x => x.Type);         
    ManyToOne(x => x.User, map => map.Column("UserId"));            
    Bag(x => x.Comments, map => { map.Key(km => km.Column("StatusId")); }, action => action.OneToMany());

    Bag(x => x.Likes, map => { map.Key(km => km.Column("StatusId"));  map.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans);  }, action => action.OneToMany());
}


public StatusLikeMap()
{
    ManyToOne(x => x.User, map => map.Column("UserId"));
    ManyToOne(x => x.Status, map => { map.Column("StatusId");  });
    Property(x => x.Date);
}
```

Delete(status) Results in this SQL:

```
UPDATE
    CommentStatus 
SET
    StatusId = null 
WHERE
    StatusId = @p0;
@p0 = ce350d55-e476-4874-9e95-341cad9342e2 [Type: Guid (0)]


UPDATE
    StatusLike 
SET
    StatusId = null 
WHERE
    StatusId = @p0;
@p0 = ce350d55-e476-4874-9e95-341cad9342e2 [Type: Guid (0)]


DELETE 
FROM
    Status 
WHERE
    Id = @p0;
@p0 = ce350d55-e476-4874-9e95-341cad9342e2 [Type: Guid (0)]
```

Any Idea ?? Help me please !

## Edit:

I made the change below and exclusion works, but this way the is database who fires the  delete command.

How can I make nhibernate execute the delete instead of database ?

```
Bag(p => p.Likes, map =>
{
   map.Key(k =>
   {
      k.Column("StatusId");
      k.OnDelete(OnDeleteAction.Cascade);
    });
    map.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
    map.Inverse(true);
 }, ce => ce.OneToMany());
```

Answer (score 1):

Cascade.DeleteOrphans only says that orphans get deleted. It doesn't mean that when the parent is deleted, the child is deleted as well.

You need to cascade "Remove" or "All" as well:

```
map.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans)
```